# How to make Table Joins in PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 Tables in phpmyadmin that need joining

`tracklisting` is my one and `catelogue` is the other, and are saved as innodb

They both have a column `CAT.NO` and would like it to be joined on this column. In catelogue it is the primary and in tracklisting it's indexed

`catelogue` is my parent and `tracklisting` would be the child as it doesn't have info for every record in catelogue. I believe this would be correct unless I'm wrong

How do I do this so that when I query  on a column in `tracklisting` it only brings up the matches for 'catelogue' because I want to know what album it's on and not my entire 60000+ catelogue

Can this be done with phpmyadmin's interface or is this a sql statement

Many thanks

EDIT:

This was the code that worked

```
SELECT *
FROM tracklisting
INNER JOIN catelogue ON catelogue.`CAT NO.` = tracklisting.`TRACKLISTING CAT NO.`
WHERE tracklisting.`ARTIST` LIKE 'placebo'
```

Thanks to everyone that helped out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont know if this can be done with the interface, but with sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  tracklisting t 
  INNER JOIN catelouge c on c.catno=t.catno 
WHERE t.id = 1
```

Comment: Just needed a bit of editing to match all my columns but that is what i wanted. O and the where clause changed to my search criteria

Answer (score 2):

You can query with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM tracklisting LEFT JOIN catelogue ON tracklisting.`CAT.NO` = catelogue.`CAT.NO` WHERE tracklisting.`<id-field>` = <id-value>`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your tracklisting has an id and you want to query with it:

```
select * from tracklisting t
inner join catelogue c on c.cat.no = t.cat.no
where t.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual join takes place in a SQL statement although with certain storage types like InnoDB you can also create foreign key references that enforce the relationship at the database level so that your inserts require the proper records to be in place and your deletes are restricted if child records exist.

Here is one way of doing the join syntax for your SQL query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tracklisting t, catalogue c
WHERE `t.CAT.NO` = `c.CAT.NO`
```

EDIT: [Here](http://www.binarytides.com/blog/create-foreign-key-using-phpmyadmin/) is a link to a tutorial for creating foreign keys in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If I setup a Foreign key will phpmyadmin be able to create the sql code i'm looking for or will that still have to be entered in manually?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, phpMyAdmin won't create the join code for you based on the foreign keys. Some PHP frameworks will do the work for you such as CakePHP and others. In those frameworks if you have the foreign key relationships configured then the framework does all the necessary joining in the queries.